# dependency injection when manually creating objects

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

I would like to take advantage of dependency injection when creating a new object.
Say that I have a `IRectangle` interface and a `Rectangle` class that implements `IRectangle`.

```
interface IRectangle {
    int Width { get; }  
    int Height { get; } 
}

class Rectangle: IRectangle {
    public int Width { get; set;}       
    public int Height { get; set;}  
}
```

Then I have an editor that allows the user to create as many rectangles as they want. In order to use the .NET Generic Host, I implemented it as a Background service.

```
class Editor: BackgroundService {
    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        for(;;) {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to create a rectangle?");
        if (Console.ReadLine() == "yes") {
            IRectangle r = new Rectangle();
        }
        }

    }

}
```

I want to replace the `new Rectangle()` part with a call to the dependency injector.

#### Additional details

I oversimplified the topic just to show where my coding problem is; someone might argue that this is not the kind of object that you create via DI.
I have two main problems with DI; it works well when the dependency is passed in the constructor; but what if I need more than one?
The second problem is when the 'chain' of constructors is interrupted.
This happens when I need a dependency in a class that is not been created by the DI container itself.

Both of these problems can be solved via a direct call to the injector, like the one I'm asking in the example.
It seems to be, however, a less-pure solution since you introduce a dependency on the DI container itself.

Do I have other options? What do you think?

##### All the code

For the sake of completeness, here is the registration part that happens in the top level statements of my program.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services)=> {
            services.AddTransient<IRectangle, Rectangle>();
            services.AddHostedService<Editor>();
            })
            
            .Build();

host.Run();
```

Comment: _"I have two main problems with DI; it works well when the dependency is passed in the constructor; but what if I need more than one?"_ - use `ActivatorUtilities`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0